# Extract data from Outlook email to excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have ~200 email a day with the following syntax:

```
Hi,

These are our clients.

548628797 FV    THD EHSI  34215564824 JUAN CARLOS CORENDA ALVARES 1          31,43
243234133 FV    THD EHSI  752520934982 JUAN CARLOS CORENDA ALVARES 2          2,8
2340291438 RFR   WER IRJF 323442342312 CARLITO HIMAT            3,00
324 EHTF  TGS HKTY  32423      WILLIAM TARING                1,2

Thank you!
```

1. Do I extract the lines between "These are our clients." and "Thank you!" ? Some emails have only 1 line and others have 20 or more. Or is better to extract from line 4 to end-1 ?
2. In excel if i paste the lines the names will be separated in different cells. I have tried:

   ```
   =IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},J2))>0, K2&" "&L2&" "&M2&" "&N2, "NO NUMBERS IN J2")
   ```

   But how can I stop the concatenated name until it hits the cell with the amount ?
3. The amount, when pasted in excel it will ignore the separator "," and just gives me instead of `31,43` the `3143` amount and I must paste it text to have the correct amount. But if I paste text, then the whole line will be inserted in one cell not in different cells.

I have a previous code that extracts table data from emails but I don't see how to implement the code to my current problem-first of all because I don't know how to look at the extraction. Extract the body in excel and replace the first 3 lines and the last line with `""` and then split the lines in columns or rows.

**The layout of the lines from what I found until now is:**

- 1 to 13 char
- 1 space
- 2 to 4 char
- if the previous has 2 char then 4 spaces/if 3 char then 3 spaces/if 4 char then 2 spaces
- 4 char always
- 1 to 11 spaces
- 1 to 15 char
- 1 to 5 spaces
- the name with up to 7 names( Spanish names ) and can have numbers at the end
- 1 to 20 spaces
- amount can be 1,00 or 1 and can be 000000000001,15 (some error that they can't correct)

**Current Code:**

```
Sub exporttheirclients()

Const FOLDER_PATH = "\\Mailbox - ME\Their clients"
Dim olkMsg As Object, _
    olkFld As Object, _
    excApp As Object, _
    excWkb As Object, _
    excWks As Object, _
    intRow As Integer, _
    intCnt As Integer, _
    data_email As String, _
    strFilename As String, _
    arrCells As Variant, _
    varb As Variant, varD As Variant, varF As Variant

Dim sinceDt, toDt As Date
sinceDt = InputBox("STARTING PERIOD")
toDt = InputBox("ENDING PERIOD")

strFilename = "C:\THEIR CLIENTS\xlsx\TCLIENTS"
If strFilename <> "" Then
    Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Set excWks = excWkb.ActiveSheet
    excApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    With excWks
        .Cells(1, 1) = "SUBJECT"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "DATE"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "REF NR"
        .Cells(1, 4) = "AMOUNT"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "CITY"
    End With
    intRow = 2
    Set olkFld = OpenOutlookFolder(FOLDER_PATH)

    For Each olkMsg In olkFld.Items
        data_email = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
        If olkMsg.Class = olMail Then
            If data_email >= sinceDt And data_email <= toDt + 1 Then
                arrCells = Split(GetCells(olkMsg.HTMLBody), Chr(255))
                For intCnt = LBound(arrCells) To UBound(arrCells) Step 16
                    On Error GoTo Handler
                    varb = arrCells(intCnt + 1)
                    varD = arrCells(intCnt + 3)
                    varF = arrCells(intCnt + 5)

                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 1) = olkMsg.Subject
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 2) = Left(olkMsg.ReceivedTime, 10)
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 3) = varb
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 4) = varD 
                    excWks.Cells(intRow, 5) = Left(varF, 4)
                    intRow = intRow + 1
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Label1:
    Next
    Set olkMsg = Nothing
    excWkb.SaveAs strFilename, 52
    excWkb.Close
    End If
    Set olkFld = Nothing
    Set excWks = Nothing
    Set excWkb = Nothing
    Set excApp = Nothing

    MsgBox "Ta dam! They have been exported ", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    Call opexl
    Exit Sub
    Handler:
    Dim myOutlookFolders As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set myOutlookFolders = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myDestFolder = Session.Folders("Mailbox - ME").Folders("Their clients").Folders("Manually input")

    If olkMsg <> "Nothing" Then

        olkMsg.Move myDestFolder
        MsgBox "An email has been found with a problem. The search continues..."

    Else: End

End If
Resume Label1:

End Sub
```

Comment: I might try to read line by line, split each line into array by spaces, and loop through the array. if the nth item of array can be converted to some kind of number, you found what you need.

Comment: and for the problem of decimals with "," I'd make a replace on the string - something like: `Replace(readLine, ",", ".")`

Comment: I see your Email body- How do you want it to show on your Excel file? can add an image example of how it should look on Excel?